# How to decide when use ADO.NET and when to connect to the database?

Tags: ado.net, relational-database

I'm learning some ADO.NET. I noticed quite a few Database functionality can also be found in ADO.NET.

I'm kind of confused. Do I use ADO.NET to manage all the interactions or should I make call to the Database?

I don't know what should be done by ADO.NET and what should be done at the database level.

Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean what should be handled in SQL statements issued from ADO.NET, and what should be done in stored procedures stored at the database level, as much as possible in stored procedures, at least that's what I live by. In addition to eliminating the chance of SQL injection, stored procedures allow you to modify sql calls without having to recompile and deploy your code as well as they enable execution plan re-use by the query optimizer.

Comment: So all the capabilities advertised in ADO.NET are just toys? Why should learn such a thing in the first place?

Comment: I don't know that I'd say they're toys, but in my experience, your life will be much easier the more you do at the database level. You're always going to use ado.net objects for connection objects and command objects, but some of the more exotic stuff I try to avoid.